# Call method in collection, when View's method called

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a view and collection like this:

```
window.DmnView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#tmpl_dmnListItem").html()),
    events: {
        "click .getWhois": "showWhois",
        "click .getDomain": "toBasket"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        return $(this.el)
                .attr("class", this.model.get("free") ? "dmnItem green" : this.model.get("checked") ? "dmnItem red" : "dmnItem red loader")
                .html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    remove: function() {
        $(this.el).remove();
    },
    showWhois: function() {
        showBoxes(this.model.get("info"));
        return false;
    },
    toBasket: function() {
        this.model.toBasket();
        console.log("view");
    }
});

window.DmnListApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#regWrap"),
    events: {
        "keypress #dmnName": "checkAll"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.input = this.$("#dmnName");
        this.list = this.$("#dmnList");
        this.basket = this.$("#dmnBasket");
        dmnList.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
        dmnList.bind('all', this.render, this);
        DmnView.bind('toBasket', this.toBasket, this);
    },
    render: function() {

    },
    addOne: function(dmnItem) {
        var view = new DmnView({model : dmnItem});
        this.list.append(view.render());
    },
    checkOne: function(name, zone, price, days) {
        dmnList.create({name: name, zone: zone, price: price, days: days});
    },
    checkAll: function(e) {
        var name = this.input.val();
        if (!name || e.keyCode != 13) return;
        if (name == "")
            name = "yandex";
        dmnList.destroyAll();
        var zoneList = dmnList.domainsInfo.Name;
        var costList = dmnList.domainsInfo.CostOrder;
        var daysList = dmnList.domainsInfo.DaysToProlong;
        var parent = this;
        $.each(zoneList, function(key, zone) {
            parent.checkOne(name, zone, costList[key], daysList[key]);
        });
        this.input.val("");
    },
    toBasket: function(){
        console.log("collection");
    }
});
```

I want Collection's method toBasket() to be called after View's method toBasket() was called. For this purpose I do the following in Collection:

```
DmnView.bind('toBasket', this.toBasket, this);
```

So, if this worked, I should receive two messages in my javascript console:

1. view
2. collection

(Maybe in other order)

But I only see "view" message in console. What I do wrong?

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.  In your collection view, you're attempting to listen to the `DmnView` event `toBasket`, but how you have it setup is a little incorrect. To listen to events, you have to bind to a specific instance you want to listen to, not a class.  So you'll want to move the bind from `initialize` to `addOne`, like this:

```
window.DmnListApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        this.input = this.$("#dmnName");
        this.list = this.$("#dmnList");
        this.basket = this.$("#dmnBasket");
        dmnList.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
        dmnList.bind('all', this.render, this);
        // Remove the DmnView bind here
    },
    addOne: function(dmnItem) {
        var view = new DmnView({model : dmnItem});
        // Bind to the DmnView instance here
        view.bind('toBasket', this.toBasket, this);
        this.list.append(view.render());
    },
    // ...
});
```

Now that your collection view is listening for the event `toBasket`, you need to actually fire the event in your `DmnView` view.

In Backbone views, no events are automatically fired, so you'll need to manually trigger it yourself, like this:

```
window.DmnView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    toBasket: function() {
        this.model.toBasket();
        console.log("view");

        // Trigger the event
        this.trigger('toBasket');
    }
});
```

You should now see both messages in your console.

Comment: Hm, I see something strange. If I have code as in my question and add manual triggering of 'toBasket' event. It have no effect. I think that the problem is that I bind event for DmnView, but in collection I create a lot of Views ( var view = new DmnView(...) ).

Comment: So, and if I simply add binding in DmnView (View) in initialize section like this.bind('toBasket', dmnListApp.toBasket, dmnListApp) - than all works as expected. Could you explain why it don't work in previous version?

Comment: Oops, you're right.  There was a small mistake in your `DmnListApp`'s `initialize` function.  `DmnView.bind('toBasket', this.toBasket, this);` is incorrect.  You need to bind to specific instances of `DmnView`, not the view class itself.  In `addOne`, you should have `view.bind('toBasket', this.toBasket, this)`.  I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Your second comment works because you're actually binding a model to its own event, which is somewhat unnecessary since the model should already know it's firing its own event. In this specific case it would be easier if you just called `dmnListApp.toBasket()` directly (assuming `dmnListApp` is a global), though I guess it isn't the cleanest way.

Comment: so, the "more good" way is to directly call global dmnListApp.toBasket(), right?

Comment: And maybe you can help me with other side of this binding:) I bind toBasket() method in the View for clicking on checkbox with class="getDomain". And after doing stuff in toBasket() method checkbox is still unchecked. Whats the problem here?

Comment: That's definitely the most straight forward way, but it does tie the views together which may not be what you want.  I just updated the answer above with a way to do it with events (thus allowing you to keep `DmnView` separate from `DmnListApp`).

Comment: Sure, do you mind making a new question though?  It's not as easy to answer in comments.

Comment: Could you help me with a new question?:)

Comment: Sure. Add a question and I'll answer if I can.